# Identity Server Password Grant to External Providers

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have implemented Identity Server 4 STS, and integrated it with external providers, AzureAD, and other custom on-prem OpenIdConnect STS. This works well for native OpenIdConnect grant types like Implicit and Hybrid, because they use HTTP redirects.

I wanted to know if it's possible to support `password` grant type to those external identity providers?

For our on on-prem STS I can implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and using api call validate user password on the back channel.

Has anyone attempted to implement similar scenario with AzureAD?

Answer (score 0):

We've done something custom to support an LDAP backend but it's still part of the normal implicit/hybrid sign in flow, just going off to a different back end store to authenticate the credentials.

Azure AD does not seem to expose any metadata saying it supports the `password` grant type via OIDC but there may be other ways of authenticating credentials via an API call.